# What's the difference between "try something" and "try something out"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "try something" and "try something out"?

I read them in the following context and did not find any difference between them:

> "That will do," he said, and the tape measure crumpled into a heap on
>   the floor. "Right then, Mr. Potter. **Try** this one. Beechwood and dragon
>   heartstring. Nine inches. Nice and flexible. just take it and give it a
>   wave."
>   Harry took the wand and (feeling foolish) waved it around a bit, but Mr.
>   Ollivander snatched it out of his hand almost at once.
>   "Maple and phoenix feather. Seven inches. Quite whippy. **Try** --"
>   Harry **tried** -- but he had hardly raised the wand when it, too, was
>   snatched back by Mr. Ollivander.
>   "No, no -here, ebony and unicorn hair, eight and a half inches, springy.
>   Go on, go on, **try it out**."
>   Harry **tried**. And **tried**. He had no idea what Mr. Ollivander was waiting
>   for. The pile of **tried** wands was mounting higher and higher on the
>   spindly chair, but the more wands Mr. Ollivander pulled from the
>   shelves, the happier he seemed to become.

My intended meanings of "try" and "try out" (by Oxford):

> try: 1.1 [with object] Use, test, or do (something new or different) in order to see if it is suitable, effective, or pleasant.
>
> try something out: Test someone or something new or different to assess their suitability or effectiveness.

Answer (score 2):

Although the two expressions overlap, there are many occasions when one fits better than the other.

For example, we tend:

> > to try a new drink/food/route/experiment/method

in the sense of seeing whether we like it or it offers us a solution.

> > to try out a new vehicle/appliance/item of sports equipment

in the sense of testing it.

> > to try on a new coat/hat/shoes

to see whether it/they fit.

but much of the time, both *try* and *try out* will do.